# Can't demonstrate why !A&B OR !A&C OR !C&B = !C&B OR !A&C

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, algebra, boolean-expression

I'm beginning a course on boolean logic and I got this boolean expression I need to prove. After a few hours of research I tried Wolfram Alpha, but unlike other equations it doesn't explain step-by-step how it simplified the longer expression. It's also pretty easy to see the (!A&B) isn't necessary in the expression with truth tables, but I can't demonstrate it. How should I do it?

The expression:

```
!A&B OR !A&C OR !C&B = !C&B OR !A&C
```

And a link to the Wolfram Alpha input: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=not%20a%20and%20b%20or%20not%20a%20and%20c%20or%20not%20c%20and%20b)

Thanks in advance, have a nice day.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra instead of directly about programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a derivation

```
!A&B | !A&C | !C&B
= !A&B&(C | !C) | !A&C&(B | !B) | !C&B&(A | !A)           // x & T = x
= !A&B&C | !A&B&!C | !A&B&C | !A&!B&C | A&B&!C | !A&B&!C  // distributive
= !A&B&C | !A&B&!C | !A&!B&C | A&B&!C                     // x | x = x
= !A&B&!C | A&B&!C | !A&B&C | !A&!B&C                     // commutative
= B&!C&(!A | A) | !A&C&(B | !B)                           // distributive
= B&!C | !A&C                                             // x | !x = T, x & T = x
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of proving these kinds of equalities. One is **formal**: *find a chain of equalities that arrive to the target formula*. The other is **intuitive**: *understand why the equality holds*. Let me try the latter.

In your case, after rewriting the left hand side of your equation we have to show that:

```
(!C&B OR !A&C) OR !A&B = !C&B OR !A&C
```

which has the form `p OR q = p`, right?

So the question becomes: *when `p OR q = p`*? In other words, *when `q` adds nothing to `p`*? Well, if `p` is a consequence of `q` then `q` adds nothing to `p`. This is if `q -> p` (i.e., `p` is a consequence of `q`) then `p OR q = p` (please prove this formally!)

So, we have to show that `!C&B OR !A&C` is a consequence of `!A&B`. But this is easy because `!A&B=true` implies `A=false` and `B=true`. So, if `C=false` we have `!C&B=true` and if `C=true` then `!A&C = true`. Hence in both cases we have `!C&B OR !A&C = true`.